# Sheaf of flat modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme. Can someone give me an (non-trivial) example of a sheaf $F$ of $\mathcal O_X$-module such that $F(U)$ is a flat $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$-module for every $U$? Is there a notion for such sheaves in literature?

A trivial example can be:

Let $X$ be an integral scheme and $K$ be the function field of $X$. Then the locally constant sheaf defined by $F(U) = K$ for any affine $U$ will be such an example. This is because for any affine $U = Spec(A)$, the functional field $K$ is indeed the field of fraction of $A$ and $A \hookrightarrow K$ is certainly flat.

P.S: I am aware of this definition: Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes and $F$ be a sheaf on $X$. Then $F$ is flat over $Y$ if for every $x\in X$, the stalk $F_x$ is a flat $\mathcal O_{Y,f(x)}$-module. But I don't think this notion is equivalent to my question .

Thanks in advance!